# Unable to create python request for post to fetch data from API-headers captured from postman do not work either

Tags: python

I need to create a post request, which is repeatedly failing as the auth headers are either being send in incorrect format or are missing/not matching signature, I need help on this as I am new to python and despite rigorous searching still cant find answer to this.

Below is the code which I got from postman for a get request but the same headers aren't working for post request, post request even doesn't work with postman either

```
import requests  
url = "https://aaaaa-bbbb.xxxx.exampleapis.net/cps/v2/enrollments?enrollmentId=81053"  
payload={} 
files={} 
headers = {   'Accept': 'application/vnd.aaaa.xxx.eeeee.v11+json',   'Authorization': 'EG1-HMAC-SHA256 c_token=cccc;access_token=aaaa;timestamp=20220526T14:06:11+0000;nonce=nnn123;signature=Abcde123=' }  
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
        
print(response.text)
```

What I have tried so far:

```
from http import client
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
import requests
import json
from hostgrid import hostAuth
from urllib.parse import urljoin,urlencode
import time
import uuid
import hashlib
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac

s = requests.Session()

url = "https://aaaa-wwww.xxxx/ppp/v2/certs?contractId=A-12345"

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = hostAuth(
    client_token= ' ctctct',
    client_secret = 'cccc',
    access_token=aaaaa'
   
)


payload = open('test.json')
data = json.load(payload)
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
nonce = uuid.uuid4().hex
hmac.new(client_secret,f'{timestamp}{nonce}'.encode('ascii'),hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
headers={
        "Accept" : "application/vnd.aaaa.ccc.cert-status.v11+json",
        'Content-Type' : "application/vnd.akamai.ccc.cert.v11+json",   
‘Authorization’  : 'EG1-HMAC-SHA256 c_token=cccc;access_token=aaaa;timestamp=20220526T14:06:11+0000;nonce=nnn123;signature=Abcde123='   
}
 
response = s.post(url,data,headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: How does the api documentation specify it takes auth headers?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman- The error says the authorization header format is incorrect

Comment: @joshmeranda- The authentication is mainly done using the API .netrc type file, which works for most of the get request, but for post it gives internal server error, so I assume it would need other information

Comment: Sample auth header for post request: Authorization:EG1-HMAC-SHA256 client_token=akaa-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
access_token=akaa-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;timestamp=20130817T02:49:13+0000;
nonce=dd9957e2-4fe5-48ca-8d32-16a772ac6d8f;signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx